# Palindrome Iterative checker in python

Tags: python

I wrote a palindrome iterative method and it returns correct result except for when the string is arena or taxi cat. It returns true for both where it has to return false.

```
def palIterative(n):
    for i in range(0, int(len(n)/2)):
        if n[i] != n[len(n) - i - 1]:
            return False
            break
        return True
```

Comment: If your code is buggy then it would be astonishingly unlikely that "arena" and "taxi cat" are the only inputs that it fails on.

Comment: Are you removing spaces?

Comment: You cannot say it *is* a palindrome until your loop is finished.

Comment: @JohnColeman: Unless they are the only non-palindromes that start and end with the same character.

Comment: @ScottHunter clearly they focused on those strings for a reason, but describing them as the only strings they fail on betrays a lack of curiosity on their part. A good first step in debugging is getting to the point where you are able to generate failures at will (by the way -- good observation on your part about why those strings fail).

Comment: @JohnColeman: "good first step" and "getting to the point" doin't usually go together :).  My guess is author is just using the test data provided, showing even *less* curiosity than you're looking for.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need `break` after the `return False` statement. Return will break out of a function. The problem though is your `return True` statement has one too many tabs. The `return True` statement should be after the for loop has completed.

Comment: Thank you, it helped

Answer (score 0):

def pallindromechecker(a):
     if a == a[::-1]:
          print("True")
     else:
          print("False")

pallindromechecker("IamaI")

Try the above code. Its an easy way to identify pallindrome

Comment: Problematic if the requirement is write an *iterative* solution.

Comment: How does this answer OP's question about why their code fails? Palindrome checkers are a dime a dozen. The world doesn't need another one.

Answer (score 0):

Your `return True` line exits the loop on the first iteration.  So the function will return True for any word that has the same first and last letter.   Also, that break statement is unnecessary because the return line above it will exit the whole function before getting to the break

Finally, to be more Pythonic, you should avoid using indexes to go through an array.  Try to use iterations on values.

For example:

```
def isPalindrome(n):
    for forward,backward in zip(n,reversed(n)):
        if forward != backward:
            return False
    return True
```

*Note that if you are looking for the shortest way to write the solution, you don't even need loops at all `return n == n[::-1]` will do it.  It is inherently iterative (as opposed to recursive) because the == comparison will iterate through the list and its reverse to compare elements (you just don't have to tell it how explicitly). You could also see as doing exactly one iteration.*

For comparison purposes, a recursive solution would look like this:

```
def isPalindrome(A):
    return not A or A[0]==A[-1] and isPalindrome(A[1:-1])
```